# What is <PrivateImplementationDetails>?

Tags: vb.net

While maintaining a piece of VB.NET code from 2012, I came across a commented line containing what seems to be VB code (in a single line, without any explanation):

```
GetType(<PrivateImplementationDetails>).GetField("$$method0x6000001-7362C34F3136BD47ED8AEFEEF3833D69BFFC1F83").FieldHandle
```

What is `<PrivateImplementationDetails>`? Is this valid syntax (the syntax debugger breaks on the first `<`)? And if so, what is its purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to [Roslyn](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/CodeGen/PrivateImplementationDetails.cs) which says:

> The main purpose of this class so far is to contain mapped fields and
>   their types.